# How to print a string with a variable in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

An exception occurred with the following code block

```
string text = "foo"

string responseText = "print: " + text;

io:println(responseText);
```

Error:

```
mismatched input 'string'. expecting {'but', ';', '?', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '==', '!=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=', '&&', '||', '&', '^', '...', '|', '?:', '..<'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the semicolon in first line.

```
string text = "foo";
io:println("print: " + text);
```